# How to get stderr separate from stdout in task-spooler jobs

Tags: stderr

I am trying to get a separate output file for stderr for jobs sent to `task-spooler` on Ubuntu 20.04.

This command works fine:

```
tsp -Lfetcher sh -c 'curl -v https://google.com'
```

But I am having trouble with the `-E` option to split stderr/stdout (per [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/tsp.1.html)).

```
tsp -Lfetcher -E sh -c 'curl -v https://google.com'
```

I expect to simply get another file like `/tmp/ts-out.VBjwOw.e`, holding stderr, to go along with `/tmp/ts-out.VBjwOw`, holding stdout. But when  I run that command, the task fails immediately (no output file is created and E-Level is set to -1) and I see this output like this written to `/tmp/socket-ts.1000.error`.

```
-------------------Error
 Msg: Reading the size of the name
 errno 0, "Success"
date Sat Dec 26 13:17:41 2020
pid 20358
type CLIENT
-------------------Warning
 Msg: JobID 9 quit while running.
 errno 2, "No such file or directory"
date Sat Dec 26 13:17:41 2020
pid 18784
type SERVER
New_jobs
<... more details about jobs>
```

Package version details

```
$ tsp -V
Task Spooler v1.0 - a task queue system for the unix user.
Copyright (C) 2007-2016  Lluis Batlle i Rossell

$ dpkg -s task-spooler
Package: task-spooler
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: misc
Installed-Size: 85
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1.0-1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
Description: personal job scheduler
 Task spooler is a Unix batch system where the tasks spooled run one
 after the other. Each user in each system has his own job queue. The tasks are
 run in the correct context (that of enqueue) from any shell/process, and its
 output/results can be easily watched. It is very useful when you know that
 your commands depend on a lot of RAM, a lot of disk use, give a lot of
 output, or for whatever reason it's better not to run them at the same time.
Original-Maintainer: Alexander Inyukhin <shurick@sectorb.msk.ru>
Homepage: http://viric.name/soft/ts/

$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
```